# Do I need a private server in order to launch MQTT really small message broker?

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying to implement push notification for my android application.

I am just wondering do I need private server for message broker.

I downloaded an open php source for android push notification from

https://github.com/tokudu/PhpMQTTClient

I uploaded those php files to my website. And then I initiated broker.exe from

really small message broker folder. When I typed my website from the

internet, My webpage displayed the message

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 192.168.0.19:1883 (Connection timed out) in /web/home/shlee/html/SAM/MQTT/sam_mqtt.php on line 640

So I used command 'telnet 192.168.0.19 1883' from command prompt.

window prompt didnt return any error message. I have almost zero knowledge about

socket and computer networking so I am guessing I must missed something important

to launch a message broker. Do I need private server to launch a message broker?

or.. is there any way to launch message broker from my own computer?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to access using external ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need a server to use RSMB it should work fine on any computer there is a binary for.

Have you checked that your windows firewall is correctly set to allow external connections on port 1883, that sounds most likely.

The php client you've chosen is not known as being very well maintained or reliable and maybe just about the most unstable and unpredictable MQTT client around! I've had more success with this one: https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT

There is an MQTT IRC channel on freenode if you're looking for specific help, it can be slow but if you hang around for long enough someone will usually answer your questions.

If you haven't already come across it Dale Lane has written some very comprehensive blog posts on using MQTT on android: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599

Comment: thanks. the code from bluerhinos looks like very comfort to read except this is my very first time with php. disabling window firewall not worked. Perhaps I asked too early. I guess I need to figure out MQTT and networking more, then come back to ask. thanks for answer.

Comment: As a follow-up, there are a range of other places to go and learn about MQTT - you can find a good list of links at http://mqtt.org/get-involved

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Oliver has said, 192.168.*.* is in the private range of IP addresses. If the computer running the web server is not also in this address range, it won't be able to connect to the computer running the broker.

In this case, yes, you'd need a private server or at least a computer with a publicly addressable IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need just this example.

This example will gives you the PHP server code and Android code.

[Tokudu example](https://github.com/tokudu/AndroidPushNotificationsDemo)